# Testing ApplicationController Filters, Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, unit-testing, rspec

I'm trying to use rspec to test a filter that I have in my ApplicationController.

In `spec/controllers/application_controller_spec.rb` I have:

```
require 'spec_helper'
describe ApplicationController do
  it 'removes the flash after xhr requests' do      
      controller.stub!(:ajaxaction).and_return(flash[:notice]='FLASHNOTICE')
      controller.stub!(:regularaction).and_return()
      xhr :get, :ajaxaction
      flash[:notice].should == 'FLASHNOTICE'
      get :regularaction
      flash[:notice].should be_nil
  end
end
```

My intent was for the test to mock an ajax action that sets the flash, and then verify on the next request that the flash was cleared.

I'm getting a routing error:

```
 Failure/Error: xhr :get, :ajaxaction
 ActionController::RoutingError:
   No route matches {:controller=>"application", :action=>"ajaxaction"}
```

However, I expect that there a multiple things wrong with how I'm trying to test this.

For reference the filter is called in `ApplicationController` as:

```
  after_filter :no_xhr_flashes

  def no_xhr_flashes
    flash.discard if request.xhr?
  end
```

How can I create mock methods on `ApplicationController` to test an application wide filter?

Answer (score 9):

To test an application controller using RSpec you need to use the [RSpec anonymous controller](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-6/docs/controller-specs/anonymous-controller) approach.

You basically set up a controller action in the `application_controller_spec.rb` file which the tests can then use.

For your example above it might look something like.

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe ApplicationController do
  describe "#no_xhr_flashes" do
    controller do
      after_filter :no_xhr_flashes

      def ajaxaction
        render :nothing => true
      end
    end

    it 'removes the flash after xhr requests' do      
      controller.stub!(:ajaxaction).and_return(flash[:notice]='FLASHNOTICE')
      controller.stub!(:regularaction).and_return()
      xhr :get, :ajaxaction
      flash[:notice].should == 'FLASHNOTICE'
      get :regularaction
      flash[:notice].should be_nil
    end
  end
end
```